# Run command on comment strings only

Tags: vim

I want to make a mapping for running the `gqq` command on the entire file (probably using the `global` command).

My question is how to make this in an intelligent way, meaning:

1. The `gqq` should be run on all lines if the file is a plain text file.
2. `gqq` should be run only on comment lines if the file is a source code file.
3. Vim should be able to detect if the file is a plain text file or if it is a source code file.

Can someone give me some help on how to achieve 2 and 3? Or point to a plugin that has this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

For item 2: you should know how to locate your comments, there must be a pattern right?

Then you can just `:g/commentPattern/norm! gqq`

Item 3: Switch on `syntax, filetype` vim should know which filetype your file is.  You can check the `filetype` to decide if it is plaintext file or src file. BTW, source codes are plaintext file too. :)

Comment: Yes, comments have patterns, but your solution for 2 is basically hard coding for each language I use. I'm almost certain there is an automatic way, something like what is used on syntax highlighting.

Comment: Regarding your solution to 3, can you provide sample commands to read the filetype detected by Vim?

Comment: @cenouro open a file in vim then `:echo &ft`